# Solving for zeroes in interpolated data in numpy/matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have some data over a 2D range that I am interested in analyzing. These data were originally in lists x,y, and z where z[i] was the value for the point located at (x[i],y[i]). I then interpolated this data onto a regular grid using

```
x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
z=np.array(z)
xi=np.linspace(minx,maxx,100)
yi=np.linspace(miny,maxy,100)
zi=griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi)
```

I then plotted the xi,yi,zi data using

```
plt.contour(xi,yi,zi)
plt.pcolormesh(xi,yi,zi,cmap=plt.get_cmap('PRGn'),norm=plt.Normalize(-10,10),vmin=-10,vmax=10)
```

This produced this plot:[image: contour plot]

In this plot you can see the S-like curve where the values are equal to zero (aside: the data doesn't vary as rapidly as shown in the colorbar -- that's simply a result of me normalizing the data to -10-10 when it actually extends far beyond that range; I did this to make the zero-valued region show up better -- maybe there's a better way of doing this too...).

The scattered dots are simply the points at which I have original data (yes, in this case my data was already on a regular grid). What I'm curious about is whether there is a good way for me to extract the values for which the curve is zero and obtain x,y pairs that, if plotted as a line, would trace that zero-region in the colormesh. I could interpolate to a really fine grid and then just brute force search for the values which are closest to zero. But is there a more automatic way of doing this, or a more automatic way of plotting this "zero-line"?

And a secondary question: I am using griddata correctly, right? I have these simple 1D arrays although elsewhere people use various meshgrids, loading texts, etc., before calling griddata.

Comment: you can plot the curve of 0 by: `c = pl.contour(..., levels=[0])`, you can also get the points on the curve from `c`. If this is what you want, I can add an answer to show how to get the points.

Comment: Thanks HYRY, that's exactly what I wanted to do. As you can see from this plot, I was able to get the line plotted with the 'levels' option: http://i61.tinypic.com/2ekkyup.png. If you wouldn't mind showing me how to easily extract the points that'd be great, and I'd happily accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y, x = np.ogrid[-1.5:1.5:200j, -1.5:1.5:200j]
f = (x**2 + y**2)**4 - (x**2 - y**2)**2

plt.figure(figsize=(9,4))
plt.subplot(121)
extent = [np.min(x), np.max(x), np.min(y), np.max(y)]
cs = plt.contour(f, extent=extent, levels=[0.1], 
     colors=["b", "r"], linestyles=["solid", "dashed"], linewidths=[2, 2])

plt.subplot(122)
# get the points on the lines
for c in cs.collections:
    data = c.get_paths()[0].vertices
    plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 
        color=c.get_color()[0],  linewidth=c.get_linewidth()[0])

plt.show()
```

here is the output:

[image]

Comment: HYRY, thanks! That's awesome! Btw, do you have a typo in the above? Did you mean "levels=[0,1]"? Because otherwise there's only one collection and specifying two colors, linestyles, etc. seems pointless. Interestingly enough, doing so makes this cool plot: http://i62.tinypic.com/2i05hk3.png. Though you can see some slight differences in the origin in the two methods in this case.

Comment: Oops, mean "near the origin".

Comment: the differences is because that level 0 contains many curves. I you need to get all the curves in level 0 you can do a for loop with `c.get_paths()[i]`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Did as you suggested and got this image: http://i57.tinypic.com/34s1fm8.png. Almost identical except for some slight graininess in the level curve. But good enough for me (I don't think any of these subtleties will affect me anyway). What determines how many Paths the level contains? Do you get a new Path for each level that's not continuous with another?